# nuxtjs/axios What is the way to initialize version 4.4.0? (nuxt.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I would like to use the nuxtjs/axios module.

At first, I install the module with npm

> npm install nuxtjs/axios

Then I set the options in the nuxt.config.js file.

```
modules: [
  ['@ nuxtjs/axios', {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost: 4000',
    browserBaseURL: '/api',
  }],
]
```

When I start the app with

> npm run dev

I expect the below output:

[image]

In nuxtjs/axios version 2.1.0, it is built as follows.

[image]

> [AXIOS] Base URL: http: // localhost: 3000 /, Browser: /

Why can not I see the above message?

I think it might be because of a problem with asyncData () {}.

Also browserBaseURL: '/ api' does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should seperate the axios module inclusion and the options.

```
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/axios'
],
axios: {
  baseURL: 'http://localhost: 4000',
  browserBaseURL: '/api'
}
```

This might just be a typo  but the module should be installed using the `npm i -S @nuxtjs/axios` command (with the @).
Also by default the browserBaseURL is set to api, so you do not have to set it manually.
Please refer to the documentation for more information: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#browserbaseurl